# c++17 Range based stream

Tags: c++, c++17

C++ has always allowed stream iterators.

```
std::ifstream   file("IntData");

for(std::istream_iterator<int> loop(file); loop != std::istream_iterator<int>(); ++loop) {
    std::cout << *loop;
}
```

Is there a proposal to add range based operator for streams? So that we can use the more modern range based for to achieve the same affect?

```
std::ifstream   file("IntData");

for(auto const& item: IterableStream<int>(file)) {
    std::cout << item;
}
```

I find myself implementing classes (like `Istream_Range`) that do this quite regularly. But I would prefer to use some standard wrapper than my home made version.

As a reference my class is simply:

```
template<typename T>
class IterableStream
{
    std::istream&      stream;
    public:
        IterableStream(std::istream& stream)
            : stream(stream)
        {}

        std::istream_iterator<T> begin() {return std::istream_iterator<T>(stream);}
        std::istream_iterator<T> end()   {return std::istream_iterator<T>();}
};
```

Now I am not trying to make it work in all `Range` situations (so it is probably missing a the appropriate types) I was just trying to get it to work with the range based for. I was hoping that something similar had been proposed for the standard.

Comment: Can't you just use an iterator range?

Comment: There's a [technical specification for ranges](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges), but it's not part of the standard for now. There is also [a good range library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) used as a base for the formal TS.

Comment: @NicolBolas: iterator range? Do you mean the boost one? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/iterator_range.html

Comment: There is range-v3 which is a quasi implementation of the mentioned Ranges-TS. Here you go with [ranges::istream_range](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/cb42d1c9cde276b2cc06f1e93685edcb278267ec/include/range/v3/istream_range.hpp)

Comment: @Maikel: No I had not seen that. But it seems a lot more complex than it needs to. Do you have a link to the Ranges-TS? Building an range (that works with for) seems to be much simpler than the one proposed (it just needs a `begin()` and `end()` end method) and I want to understand why.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if all (?) iterators in std followed the pattern introduced in `std::filesystem::directory_iterator`;

```
namespace std
{
template <class TTy, class TElem, class TTraits, class TDiff>
istream_iterator<TTy, TElem, TTraits, TDiff>
   begin(const istream_iterator<TTy, TElem, TTraits, TDiff>& it)
{
   return it;
}

template <class TTy, class TElem, class TTraits, class TDiff>
istream_iterator<TTy, TElem, TTraits, TDiff>
   end(const istream_iterator<TTy, TElem, TTraits, TDiff>&)
{
   return {};
}
}
```